# mysqli orientado a objetos

Tags: php, mysqli

que es lo que estoy haciendo mal tengo esta sentencia sql que deberia arrojarme `1` y me esta arrojando `0` mi codigo con consulta preparada:

```
<?php
 session_start();
include"conexion.php";

$me=$_SESSION["id"];
$id= $_GET["id"];


$sql=$conexion->prepare("SELECT de,para FROM amigos WHERE de=? AND para=?");

$sql->bind_param('ii', $me, $para);
$sql->execute();

$rows=$sql->num_rows;
  echo $rows;//esto deberia arrojarme 1 pero me arroja 0

$sql->close();


?>
```

pero si la consulta no es  preparada si me arroja el resultado esperado

```
<?php
 session_start();
include"conexion.php";

$me=$_SESSION["id"];
$id= $_GET["id"];

$sql=$conexion->query("SELECT de,para FROM amigos WHERE de='$me' AND para='$id'");

  echo $sql->num_rows;//resultado esperado 1
```

alguien me puede dar una mano recien estoy empesando a aprender la forma orientada a objetos gracias!

Comment: ¿Podrías poner la estructura de la tabla (al menos la parte relacionada a las columnas de y para? También sería bueno añadir un ejemplo de los valores en la tabla y los que usas para la sentencia. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: `de`y `para ` son de tipo entero (int) @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: Las dos sentencias no son iguales exactamente. En una estás comparando cadenas mientras en la otra estás pasando valores enteros. Aunque creo que eso no debería afectar en este caso (dependiendo de los valores)

Comment: podrias decirme en cual de las dos ?

Comment: En la primera que muestras estás indicando que el binding es de valores numéricos (la i), en la segunda envuelves los valores con comillas. Como te decía antes, sería ideal que pusieras ejemplos de valores de la tabla y valores que pasas como parámetro a las sentencias (session id y el get id) para que podamos ver qué puede estar pasando.

Comment: pero si son valores enteros @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: ¿Qué valor tienes en `$_SESSION[“id”]` y en `$_GET[“id”]` cuando realizas la consulta? ¿Tienes esos valores en la tabla?

Comment: recojos esos valores mediante un click a un boton `$_SESSION[“id”]` es el id de session de los usuarios proviene de un campo tipo entero y `$_GET[“id”]` tambien es un estero

Comment: Eso no responde a mi pregunta. De todos modos, échale un ojo a `store_result()`. Creo que te puede servir de ayuda.

Comment: gracias @AlvaroMontoro  voy a checar a ver

Comment: Ya probaste haciendo la insercion en la base de datos ?, debes empezar a depurar, primero la bd, luego la conexcion a la BD, luego los parametros que lleguen asegurarte que no llegue ningun null, y por ultimo capturar que error te esta devolviendo, para que se nos sea mas facil de idnetificar el error, ya que si devuelve un 0 es porque hay algun fallo en el query

Comment: Estás usando una variale **`$para`** que no existe. Tú capturas el criterio en **una variable llamada `$id`**, debería corregirse haciendo esto:  `$sql->bind_param('ii', $me, $id);`  Confunde que, en el segundo caso, uses las comillas simples tratándose de enteros.  Si no te funciona como he dicho antes, entonces cambia las `ii` por `ss`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay dos problemas en tu código:

- Estás capturando el criterio en una variable `$id`, pero en el bind usas una variable `$para` que no existe.
- Si revisas la [documentación de `num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php) verás que este método depende de `store_result` para funcionar de forma adecuada:

> Devuelve el número de filas de un conjunto de resultados. El uso de
>   `mysqli_stmt_num_rows()` depende de si se utiliza
>   `mysqli_stmt_store_result()` para almacenar en buffer el conjunto de
>   resultados completo en el gestor de sentencia.
>
> Si se usa `mysqli_stmt_store_result()`, `mysqli_stmt_num_rows()` puede
>   llamarse inmediatamente.

**Es decir, si no invocas `store_result` antes de `num_rows`, será imposible saber el número de filas que trajo la consulta y obtendrás siempre `0` por este motivo.**

El código debería funcionar entonces si corregimos esos dos fallos:

```
<?php
 session_start();
include"conexion.php";

$me=$_SESSION["id"];
$id= $_GET["id"];


$sql=$conexion->prepare("SELECT de,para FROM amigos WHERE de=? AND para=?");

$sql->bind_param('ii', $me, $id);
$sql->execute();

$sql->store_result();    
$rows=$sql->num_rows;
echo $rows;//esto deberia arrojarme 1 pero me arroja 0

$sql->close();


?>
```

Comment: muy talentoso @A. cedano muchas gracias con eso funciono bien, recien estoy empesando con las consultas preparadas por eso soy un poco ignorante en el temas saludos y exitos!!